# Creating an ElasticSearch query to search all fields and use partial matching at the same time

Tags: elasticsearch

Separately, I have partial search working and I can search all fields. But I'm unable use partial matching on a search that maps all fields.

This returns my name when I use partial matching:

```
GET /_search?pretty=true
{ 
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "FullName": "andon"
        }
    }
}
```

This search runs on all fields, but doesn't do partial matching (0 hits):

```
GET /_search?pretty=true
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": "andon"
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to combine partial matching with a search on all fields & types?  I have many fields and types so I'm hoping to avoid having to specify them all manually.

If it makes any difference, I'm inserting my data from a River that connects to SQL.

**EDIT:**  I now have the _all field in my mapping.  It appears to make no difference.

```
PUT /contact/
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "nGram",
                        "min_gram" : "1",
                        "max_gram" : "10"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
            "properties" : {
                "Description":{"type":"string","store":"yes", "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"},
                "OfficePhone":{"type":"string","store":"yes"},
                "Email":{"type":"string","store":"yes", "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"},
                "FullName":{"type":"string","store":"yes", "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"},
                "ReportsTo":{"type":"string","store":"yes"},
                "Department":{"type":"string","store":"yes", "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"},
                "Title":{"type":"string","store":"yes", "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `"_all" : {"enabled" : true}` in your mapping? see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

Comment: @maxivanov I didn't, but I do now. Please see my edit

Comment: Can you reproduce it? I just can't: https://gist.github.com/maximivanov/8958787

Comment: @maxivanov In your put statement, be sure to put "brandon", else it *is* a full match. Also, using your exact code, no I cannot get it to work. It returns 0 results. I'm running 0.90.0

Comment: Here's a pastebin very similar to yours. The exact search works, the partial name search does not. http://pastebin.com/SMtiR8wr

Comment: see Alex's answer, I think that's what it is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`_all`-field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) works by taking the text for all fields, pass them through the analyzer for `_all` (which is `standard` unless overridden), then index the resulting terms.

It does *not* take whatever terms are made by the analyzers for the other fields and shove them all into the same field.

Thus, you'd have to override the `_all`-field to use your custom analyzer.

But! I don't think you'd really want to do that. You'll get a much larger index. Having `_all` is convenient at times, but it's usually better to control what fields are searched at search time.

So instead of doing a `match` on `_all`, you probably want to be using [`multi_match`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), specifying your fields. You can also consider [`copy_to`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/mapping-core-types.html#copy-to) if you're on 1.0.

Comment: I upgraded to 1.0.  The copy_to feature is exactly what I was looking for. I created a new field that I used the ngram analyzer on and I just copied all the fields I wanted into it.

Comment: @Brandon - Could you find some solution working ? If Yes, would it be possible to share the ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching with wildcard characters(%2A) and was able to do partial searches

ex => ?q=chew%2A&size=100